# Dynamic url for images on s3 in Django

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-templates

I want to show the user's image

I try with:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static Logos/{{user.photo}}.png %}" />
```

and

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static Logos/{% user.photo %}.png %}" />
```

but I get this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at Could not parse the remainder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not have `{{..` or `{%..` within a `{%..%}`. Hence the error.

You can use [`get_static_prefix` instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#the-get-static-prefix-templatetag)

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}{{user.photo}}.jpg" />
```

OR

[`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.core.context_processors.static) by including the appropriate context processor, which is `django.core.context_processors.static`

So the usage would be :

```
{{STATIC_URL}}{{user.photo}}.jpg
```

Comment: I could solve it in the following way:

    <img src="{% static 'Logos' %}/{{user.photo}}.png" />

where Logos is the folder on S3 that have the photos.